An estimate in Hardy space.
Consider function $u=(u_1,u_2):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, and define $\nabla^\perp=(\partial_2,-\partial_1)$, I attempt to show that
$$\lVert \nabla u_1\cdot \nabla^\perp u_2 \rVert_{\mathcal{H}^1}\le C\lVert\nabla u \rVert_{L^2}^2 ,$$
where $\mathcal{H}^1$ is the Hardy space in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Due to my limited knowledge about Hardy space(only the definition and Poisson characterization is known), I cannot find proper tools to derive the above estimate. Can anyone give a proof or hint?
